# Python reading stdin from PIPE not blocking

Tags: python, subprocess

Here's the code reduced for simplicity.

**server.py**

```
import sys

while True:
    for line in sys.stdin:
        # Do something here
```

**client.py**

```
import subprocess
import sys

p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "server.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

When I run **server.py** directly python blocks at the `sys.stdin` read in the for loop when there is no data in `stdin`. This is as expected.

When I run **client.py**, which runs **server.py** in a subprocess with stdin connected to a PIPE, then server.py no longer blocks at the for loop reading in stdin, which results in my CPU usage hitting 100%. This is because the loop runs infinitely instead of blocking when there is nothing to read from stdin.

What is it about connecting stdin to PIPE in subprocess that is causing this? Is there a way around it? I would like for the for loop to block when there is no data to read for stdin.